# How to extract dd-wrt firmware image for development?

Tags: php, linux, router, firmware, dd-wrt

I am a beginner in dd-wrt firmware development. I have a Linksys router (Model Number E900) and download the suitable firmware for this model from dd-wrt website to customize this [firmware](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Linksys_E900) web pages for some personal requirements. I know dd-wrt is allow to open source development.

I using [firmware mod kit](https://code.google.com/p/firmware-mod-kit/) for rebuild the firmware. But a problem when I 
try to extract the firmware using firmware mod kit it's shows the error like below.

[image]

I try to extract this image using 7zip software. But it's shows error like below

[image]

I think the firmware image is a password protected. But it's open source?

How to extract this password protected firmware image in Linux terminal?

Comment: You're not root and doesn't look like you're using `sudo` either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems some permission issue or extract.sh was not able to extract properly. i have extracted the same bin file with new firmware-mod-kit

so try the updated one, use **extract-ng.sh** for extraction and **build-ng.sh**
 to build

http://www.devttys0.com/2011/09/firmware-mod-kit-updated-v-069-released/

https://github.com/lattera/dd-wrt

Comment: Instead of posting links as answer add some text to explanation how this answer help to OP in fixing current issue.Thanks

Comment: Okay !!! i too tried the old firmware mod kit for this same bin file and got error saying "bin file is not correct" and "file-system is not supported". And got success with this new mod kit, that's all

Answer (score 0):

check out firmware-mod-kit wiki page. 
https://code.google.com/p/firmware-mod-kit/wiki/Documentation?tm=6

according to provided information, actually, the error message had given you quite enough information about what's going on. "Check pre-requisites"

The very first step on wiki page is about PREREQUISITES, to prepare your environment.